# mount a windows folder in solaris 11.3

Tags: solaris, shell, oracle, solaris-11

I want to check a folder which is placed in a windows server by my Oracle RDBMS12C. therefore based on my research first I need to mount the windows folder in solaris  11.3. we are using spark server.

I try to use below structure but I am not sure what is wrong with my format would you mind help me:

**Format:**

```
mount -F smbfs //[workgroup;][user[:password]@]server/share mount-point
```

**my command:**

```
mount -F smbfs //MyWorkGroup;MyUSERNAME:MyPASSWORD@182.126.18.36/Share10 /myshare
```

I used below reference:
[Oracle Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/820-2429/mountsharetask/index.html)

I am receiving below error:

My password contains @ so it break into 2 part.

```
mount: Mount point cannot be determined
-bash: USERNAME:PASSWORD PART1: command not found
[2] 28436
-bash: PASSWORD PART2@182.126.18.36/Share10: No such file or directory
[2]   Exit 127                USERNAME:PASSWORD PART1
```

Also I want to check with you, many example used /mnt  as destination, but I created a folder and called it "myshare" and I want to mount it to that folder, is this approach correct?

---

based on AndrewHenle comment I edited my script to:

```
mount -F smbfs '//MyWorkGroup;MyUSERNAME:MyPASSWORD@182.126.18.36/Share10' /pshare
```

Now I am receiving this error:

```
/usr/lib/fs/smbfs/mount: can't resolve name "MyWorkGroup;MyUSERNAME:MyPASSWORD@182.126.18.36", node name or service name not known
```

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I added error also

Comment: It looks like your mount command is getting split by `bash` into two command at the `;` character.  Bash treats the `;` character special - IIRC, it's a command separator.  So you either need to escape it as `\;`, or enclose the entire argument in single quotes:  `'//MyWorkGroup;MyUSERNAME:MyPASSWORD@182.126.18.36/Share10'`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783701/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-bash-how-do-we-know-it

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I am receiving below error now:
 can't resolve name "MyWorkGroup;MyUserName:My@Password@182.126.18.36", node name or service name not known